Why does this VBA function cause errors on open from sharepoint / onedrive? How to fix?
I have a workbook stored on sharepoint / onedrive and when I open it I get the error "the file could not be accessed" which I believe is related to the length of the path of the file.
It's a strange error, because the path appears to be fine, and when you click okay to acknowledge the error the workbook opens anyway. The only negative consequence of this error is that it causes some cells to resolve to a #VALUE error.
These cells all contain the same formula which has two VBA functions. When the cells are manually refilled (double clicking to autofill the range, or by clicking on the formula and pressing enter) then the #VALUE error disappears.
The function is:
=LET(
named_range,GetNamedRange([@[named range string]]),
arg1,[@[arg1]],
arg2,[@[arg2]],
bilinterp(named_range,arg1,arg2))

The first VBA function is GetNamedRange which is a massive switch statement (to avoid using the volotile INDIRECT):
Public Function GetNamedRange(NamedRangeString As String) As Range

Dim NamedRange As Range

Select Case NamedRangeString

Case "example_1"
Set NamedRange = Range("example_1")
Case "example_2"
Set NamedRange = Range("example_2")

...

etc

The second VBA function is bilinterp:
Public Function bilinterp(table As Range, dCol As Double, dRow As Double) As Variant

' Returns the bilinear interpolation of Table using dCol and dRow
' Table must be in ascending order left to right by the first row,
'    and top to bottom by the first column
' Algorithm from http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=64224
     
    Dim nRow As Long, nCol As Long ' dimensions of table
    Dim lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long 'bounding rows
    Dim lCol1 As Long, lCol2 As Long ' bounding columns
    Dim rf As Double, cf As Double ' row and column fractions, 0..1
    Dim sL As Double, sR As Double ' column header values flanking dCol
    Dim sT As Double, sB As Double ' row header values flanking dRow
     
     ' four corner table values flanking dCol, dRow
    Dim sTL As Variant, str As Variant, sBR As Variant, sBL As Variant
     
    nRow = table.rows.count
    nCol = table.Columns.count
     
     ' Table must be at least 3x3 including header row and column
    If nRow < 3 Or nCol < 3 Then GoTo BadTable
     
     ' value to be interpolated must lie within row and column data
    If dCol < table(1, 2) Then GoTo BadData
    If dCol > table(1, nCol) Then GoTo BadData
    If dRow < table(2, 1) Then GoTo BadData
    If dRow > table(nRow, 1) Then GoTo BadData
     
    lCol1 = Application.Match(dCol, table(1, 2).Resize(, nCol - 1)) + 1
    sL = table(1, lCol1)
    If dCol = sL Then
        lCol2 = lCol1
        sR = sL
        cf = 0#
    Else
        lCol2 = lCol1 + 1
        sR = table(1, lCol2)
        cf = (dCol - sL) / (sR - sL) ' column fraction
    End If
     
    lRow1 = Application.Match(dRow, table(2, 1).Resize(nRow - 1)) + 1
    sT = table(lRow1, 1)
    If dRow = sT Then
        lRow2 = lRow1
        sT = sB
        rf = 0#
    Else
        lRow2 = lRow1 + 1
        sB = table(lRow2, 1)
        rf = (dRow - sT) / (sB - sT)
    End If
    
    sTL = table(lRow1, lCol1)
    str = table(lRow1, lCol2)
    sBR = table(lRow2, lCol2)
    sBL = table(lRow2, lCol1)
    
    If sTL = "-" Or str = "-" Or sBR = "-" Or sBL = "-" Then GoTo BadData
    
     ' Compute the weighted sum of four locations in Table
    bilinterp = CDbl(sTL) * (1 - rf) * (1 - cf) _
    + CDbl(str) * (1 - rf) * cf _
    + CDbl(sBR) * rf * cf _
    + CDbl(sBL) * rf * (1 - cf)
     
    Exit Function
     
BadTable:
    bilinterp = "Table must be at least 3x3"
    Exit Function
BadData:
    bilinterp = "none"
    Exit Function
End Function

This pattern is used in other formulas in the workbook (i.e. a using a VBA switch statement to get a named range followed by another VBA function which uses that named range as an argument), so I'm not sure why this one particular range is resolving to the #VALUE error. It's also strange that when you manually repopulate the range the error disappears.
I'd love to know what's causing this error / if there is any way to resolve it, no matter how.
Many thanks.
Edit:
This question and top answer seems quite promising and might provide some additional info.

Excel does like to make certain properties of a range unavailable during certain stages of calcualtion.


The problem was with Event Handlers. The workbook contains a series of event handlers like Workbook_Open, Worksheet_Change, etc. Every now and then, one of the actions taken by these event handlers will cause some cells in the workbook to recalculate. If excel triggers a recalculation while a macro is running, any cells containing this UDF will result in an error.


There were actually two possible solutions. The first solution I found was to disable automatic calculation at the beginning the Event Handlers, and re-enable it afterwards. For some reason, even though a macro is running at the time calculation is set back to xlCalculationAutomatic, it will cause the UDFs to be successfully re-evaluated, and the property is available.

My workbook does have some worksheet change events, which could be a cause of the named range not being recognised properly. However, if I add Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual at the start of my events and Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic at the end of my events, as the post suggests, it doesn't solve my problem at all, unfortunately.
